# How to replace a number to another number in a specific column using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

This is probably basic but I am completely new to command-line and using awk.
I have a file like this:

```
1 RQ22067-0 -9
2   RQ34365-4   1
3   RQ34616-4   1
4   RQ34720-1   0
5   RQ14799-8   0
6   RQ14754-1   0
7   RQ22101-7   0
8   RQ22073-1   0
9   RQ30201-1   0
```

I want the 0s to change to 1 in column3. And any occurence of 1 and 2 to change to 2 in column3. So essentially only  changing numbers in column 3. But I am not changing the -9.

```
1 RQ22067-0 -9
2   RQ34365-4   2
3   RQ34616-4   2
4   RQ34720-1   1
5   RQ14799-8   1
6   RQ14754-1   1
7   RQ22101-7   1
8   RQ22073-1   1
9   RQ30201-1   1
```

I have tried using (see below) but it has not worked

```
>> awk '{gsub("0","1",$3)}1' PRS_with_minus9.pheno.txt > PRS_with_minus9_modified.pheno
>> awk '{gsub("1","2",$3)}1' PRS_with_minus9.pheno.txt > PRS_with_minus9_modified.pheno
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting to change the number as a whole, or individual digits? Do you want a line like `foo bar 10` to become `foo bar 21` or remain unaltered?

Answer (score 4):

With this code in your question:

```
awk '{gsub("0","1",$3)}1' PRS_with_minus9.pheno.txt > PRS_with_minus9_modified.pheno
awk '{gsub("1","2",$3)}1' PRS_with_minus9.pheno.txt > PRS_with_minus9_modified.pheno
```

1. you're running both commands on the same input file and writing their
   output to the same output file so only the output of the 2nd script
   will be present in the output, and
2. you're trying to change 0 to 1
   first and THEN change 1 to 2 so the $3s that start out as 0 would
   end up as 2, you need to change the order of the operations.

This is what you should be doing, using your existing code:

```
awk '{gsub("1","2",$3); gsub("0","1",$3)}1' PRS_with_minus9.pheno.txt > PRS_with_minus9_modified.pheno
```

For example:

```
$ awk '{gsub("1","2",$3); gsub("0","1",$3)}1' file
1 RQ22067-0 -9
2 RQ34365-4 2
3 RQ34616-4 2
4 RQ34720-1 1
5 RQ14799-8 1
6 RQ14754-1 1
7 RQ22101-7 1
8 RQ22073-1 1
9 RQ30201-1 1
```

The `gsub()` should also just be `sub()`s as you only want to perform each substitution once, and you don't need to enclose the numbers in quotes so you could just do:

```
awk '{sub(1,2,$3); sub(0,1,$3)}1' file
```

Comment: How can you avoid the spaces between field 1 and 2 being truncated?

Comment: @WalterA there's several options including setting FS and OFS to the number of blanks (or tab?) that are present in the input or using fixed width fields or doing the replacement on the whole record, e.g. `sub(/1$/,2)` instead of modifying a field with `sub(1,2,$3)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the value of column 3 and then update the field value.

Check for 1 as the first rule because if the first check is for 0, the value will be set to 1 and the next check will set the value to 2 resulting in all 2's.

```
awk '
{
  if($3==1) $3 = 2
  if($3==0) $3 = 1
}
1' file
```

Output

```
1 RQ22067-0 -9
2 RQ34365-4 2
3 RQ34616-4 2
4 RQ34720-1 1
5 RQ14799-8 1
6 RQ14754-1 1
7 RQ22101-7 1
8 RQ22073-1 1
9 RQ30201-1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples and ternary operators try following code. Simple explanation would be, checking condition if 3rd field is 1 then set it to 2 else check if its 0 then set it to 0 else keep it as it is, finally print the line.

```
awk '{$3=$3==1?2:($3==0?1:$3)} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

***Generic solution:*** Adding a Generic solution here, where we can have 3 `awk` variables named: `fieldNumber` in which you could mention all field numbers which we want to check for. 2nd one is: `existValue` which we want to match(in condition) and 3rd one is: `newValue` new value which needs to be there after replacement.

```
awk -v fieldNumber="3" -v existValue="1,0" -v newValue="2,1" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(fieldNumber,arr1,",")
  num1=split(existValue,arr2,",")
  num2=split(newValue,arr3,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
    value[arr2[i]]=arr3[i]
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if($arr1[i] in value){
       $arr1[i]=value[$arr1[i]]
     }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\S+/\n&\n/3;h;y/01/12/;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n.*/\2\1/' file
```

Surround 3rd column by newlines.

Make a copy.

Replace all `0`'s by `1`'s and all `1`'s by `2`'s.

Append the original.

Pattern match on newlines and replace the 3rd column in the original by the 3rd column in the amended line.

Answer (score 0):

Also with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {s=$3;sub(/1/,"2",s);sub(/0/,"1",s);$3=s} 1' file
1 RQ22067-0 -9
2 RQ34365-4 2
3 RQ34616-4 2
4 RQ34720-1 1
5 RQ14799-8 1
6 RQ14754-1 1
7 RQ22101-7 1
8 RQ22073-1 1
9 RQ30201-1 1
```

- the substitutions are made with `sub()` on a copy of `$3` and then the copy with the changes is assigned to $3.

Comment: Why the check for `NR > 1`?

Comment: Well,  the first record doesn't receive any substitution. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't like the simple

```
sed 's/1$/2/; s/0$/1/' file
```

you might want to play with

```
sed -E 's/(.*)([01])$/echo "\1$((\2+1))"/e' file
```